# React: GraphQL String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm currently working on a gatsby project and a little stuck with queries.

Situation: I have a query of 6 teams, I would like to have 6 different buttons and based on if one of the buttons is selected, my website will display only that team instead of all 6

Problem: I'm working with GraphQL query and I'm aware that the query changes only on build. So my method of using `String interpolation` doesn't work

Query:

```
query {
allFile(filter: childMarkdownRemark {frontmatter: {title: {eq: ${selectedTeam }}}}}) {
                      edges {
                        node {
                          relativePath
                          childMarkdownRemark {
                            frontmatter {
                              title
                              teamDesc
                              teamPara
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

In my case `selectedTeam` is just a react `state` that is being updated everytime one of the teams is being clicked. Example: `const [ selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam ] = useState('Executives')`

Is there no way I can work around this or do I need to manually create a conditional rendering?

Comment: Just use a GraphQL variable?

Comment: @Bergi could you please elaborate

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#query-variables

Comment: @Bergi so basically use them as `$selectedTeam`? I'm quite confused after reading the documentation. I'm not sure where is the `$selectedTeam` needs to defined in the first place?

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: I still don't understand, where am I suppose to keep the declared variables? Can I keep it in the same file, where my query is declared?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242483/discussion-between-fill-and-bergi).

Comment: Where is your query declared currently? Where does that declaration get `selectedTeam` from? What are you doing with the query?

Comment: @Bergi I've sent you a private chat message to avoid spam over here

Comment: There's no spam. Either it's useful for all readers with similar problems, or I won't answer it anyway.